# Firefox distorts text

Tags: windows-8, firefox, fonts

[image: some text shown in the image is difficult to read]
[image: some text shown in the image is difficult to read]

This is Firefox 22 on Windows 8 pro.

Comment: Probably this issue: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952985 - I'll write this up as an answer if it ends up disabled hardware acceleration or removing the update works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be this known issue: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952985

Quoting from the answers there:

> Try to disable hardware acceleration in Firefox.
>
> - Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Browsing: "Use hardware    acceleration when available"
> - https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes
> - https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/09/hardware-acceleration/
>
> Try to set the gfx.content.azure.enabled pref to false or if this
>   didn't help disable Direct2D by setting the gfx.direct2d.disabled pref
>   to true on the about:config page and leave hardware acceleration
>   otherwise enabled.
>
> - http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config

Alternatively:

> The actual problem (atleast for me and a few others) is due to a
>   windows update kb2670838. This update applies performance patches to
>   Direct2D, 3D, and Write related components. The reason disabling usage
>   of Direct2D or hardware acceleration fixes it is because its simply
>   not using those Direct___ functions anymore.
>
> In the Update history, 2670838 is listed as: Platform update for
>   Microsoft Windows (KB2670838) In the Installed updates, 2670838 is
>   listed as: Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2670838)
>
> Again, uninstalling this update solved the problem for me and a few
>   others, hopefully it will solve your problems correctly as well.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838